# How can I remove a dado strip of wallpaper without damaging the wall?

Tags: wallpaper

I'm redoing my bedroom under a tight budget. I have a narrow strip of wallpaper circumscribing the room with a vomitous pattern that sucks the life out of the area. The drywall is painted underneath it, so I don't want to destroy the drywall with moisture or scratch away too much paint. The wallpaper is not dry-stripping but doesn't seem to be laminated either.

Is there any way I can remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used to carefully use water and it would come off pretty easily with some gentle scraping.  Just do not crazy soak the wall.  If you keep the wallpaper damp you should be able to carefully remove it with a scraper.  It should not hurt the drywall especially if there is paint on it.  Try this on a small area first.

[Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/catalog/servlet/ContentView?pn=wallpaper_removal_techniques_removers_and_strippers_HT_BG_PA&storeId=10051&langId=-1&catalogId=10053) has a good description on other ways to do it.

Comment: A plastic taping knife is pretty good at scraping softened paper without chewing into the wallboard as a metal knife might do.

Answer (score 0):

[Paper tiger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000DI7WP) (brand name, generic: wallpaper scoring tool) puts small breaks in the paper to allow water to penetrate, freeing its hold.

[image]

Comment: This works well for large sections of wallpaper, but if the strip is thinner than the tool it will likely be an issue, no?

Comment: That's a pretty skinny strip @MichaelBoratko
.  If it's that thin, sponging on water will get it to release in-a-jiffy.